# How run inference using TensorRT on multiple GPUs?

Tags: tensorrt

I converted a resnet50 TensorFlow model to a TensorRT engine. When I run inference, it only uses one of my GPUs. I have two RTX3090 GPUs. How can I run inference on more than one GPU?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [TensorRT documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/developer-guide/index.html#faq):

> Each ICudaEngine object is bound to a specific GPU when it is instantiated, either by the builder or on deserialization. To select the GPU, use cudaSetDevice() before calling the builder or deserializing the engine. Each IExecutionContext is bound to the same GPU as the engine from which it was created. When calling execute() or enqueue(), ensure that the thread is associated with the correct device by calling cudaSetDevice() if necessary.

So, the same engine cannot be accelerated using multiple GPUs. However, you can implement an embarrassingly parallel approach by instantiating multiple ICudaEngine and IExecutionContext objects and bound each pair to a separate GPU.